# Rich Text Area field not allowing to save <style> tag

Tags: community, richtextarea

I am saving my email body in a field whose data type is RichTextArea so basically I am saving email history into a database. My email body sometimes contains style tags too but when trying to save  tag into RichTextArea  field then salesforce is not allowing & truncating style tag. So if I save "xyz_css" into the database from developer console & when I refresh then I can see only text "xyz_css" is saved. What I observed is that my RichTextArea field saves other tags (like ) but truncate style tag.

I know as per best practice we should have inline style but want to know is there any security concern this field has or is there any issue with RichTextArea.

Answer (score 1):

The **rich text area** only supports some of the formattings and not all that is possible using style.

**Unsupported styles are removed** and added just as plain text.

[Refer to this salesforce article for more details.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&type=5)

> **NOTE** We recommend using the toolbar to format your content. The rich
> text editor provides only a WYSIWYG interface. You can’t edit HTML
> tags. When you copy content from a web page or another source and
> paste it into the editor, unsupported tags are removed. Text enclosed
> in unsupported tags is preserved as plain text. HTML markup counts
> against the character limit of the field. For more information, see
> [Rich Text Area Field Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=fields_rich_text_area_limitations.htm&type=5&language=en_US).